# Invert selection in SPSS

Tags: selection, spss, inversion

I have a large table from which I need to drop cases.

I need to drop only those properties which were demolished before April 2011 (formatted as 201104).

From expeience elsewhere, I would expet this to be dead simple.

Select all cases "where EndDate < 201104", INVERT SELECTION and save the selected cases to a new file.

The numeric field "EndDate" (date of demolition) is only populated for demolished properties, so I cannot do "where EndDate > 201104".

But I cannot find INVERT SELECTION anywhere.

Thought also of

```
NUMERIC Flag (F1.0) .
COMPUTE Flag = 1 .
```

select all cases "where EndDate < 201104"
    COMPUTE Flag = 2 .

and then saving 
    "where flag = 2"
but this applies flag = 2 to all cases.

Is there a good reason why this SIMPLE selection inversion tool is not available?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1):

If `EndDate` is missing for all the cases you want to select, you can simply use

`SELECT IF MISSING(EndDate).`

Equivalently here is how you would calculate a flag to select out specific cases. Initialize to a number and then assign `EndDate < 201104` to a different number, then select the original initialized number.

```
data list free / EndDate ShouldKeep.
begin data
201101 0
201102 0
201103 0
. 1
. 1
. 1
. 1
end data.

*select if MISSING(EndDate).
*exe.

compute #flag = 0.
if (EndDate < 201104) #flag = 1.
select if #flag = 0.
exe.
```

You could also recode missing `EndDate` values to a date after 201104.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, is missing for only the majority of properties I want to select. I will investigate your other suggestions.

Comment: The principal question remains: is there an INVERT SELECTION command?

Comment: @BruceMitchell, No, not as you want it here. As you said, if there weren't missing data just switching the sign of `EndDate < 201104` to `EndDate >= 201104` would work. The problem is the missing values, and indeed I wouldn't want `EndDate >= 201104` to return true for missing values! The solution I posted using a flag variable  (or using MISSING) should be amenable to work for any general solution of flagging cases that include missing values.

Comment: You could also do something like `select if (EndDate < 201104) <> 1 or MISSING(EndDate) = 1.` The main point is if you evaluate an expression with a missing value you get a missing value returned (unless the function specifically allows it). The CSR states `If the logical expression is indeterminate because of missing values, the case is not selected. In a simple relational expression, a logical expression is indeterminate if the expression on either side of the relational operator is missing.`

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do something similar:
do your "select if" as usual, when you're happy with the result as a negative of what you want, you add a line of recode. Here's an example, in which I want to select all cases that match two criterias (code = "2102P11" and sitzung = 4). I wasn't happy with the result, it was the opposite of what I wanted.

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
USE ALL.
COMPUTE filter_$=(CODE = "2102P11" AND sitzung = 4).
VARIABLE LABELS filter_$ 'CODE = "2102P11" AND sitzung = 4 (FILTER)'.
VALUE LABELS filter_$ 0 'Not Selected' 1 'Selected'.
FORMATS filter_$ (f1.0).
FILTER BY filter_$.
EXECUTE.
```

you can invert the selection by adding recode (into the same variable):

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
USE ALL.
COMPUTE filter_$=(CODE = "2102P11" AND sitzung = 4).
VARIABLE LABELS filter_$ 'CODE = "2102P11" AND sitzung = 4 (FILTER)'.
VALUE LABELS filter_$ 0 'Not Selected' 1 'Selected'.
FORMATS filter_$ (f1.0).
RECODE filter_$ (1=0) (0=1).
FILTER BY filter_$.
EXECUTE.
```